# ¿Cómo mantener un archivo en un formulario php después de un reload?

Tags: php, formularios, archivo

Tengo un formulario **php** con validaciones. Si algún campo es obligatorio y no se rellena, se muestra un mensaje de error al enviarlo y se mantiene el valor de los demás campos que había introducido el usuario (para texto utilizo **$_REQUEST['nombreDelCampo']**. Sin embargo, en el caso de tener un archivo cargado (como una imagen), se pierde cuando se envía en formulario con errores, siendo necesario volver a seleccionar el archivo.
¿Hay alguna forma de mantener este archivo aunque haya errores en el formulario para evitar seleccionarlo de nuevo? Entiendo que será alguna variable del tipo **$_FILES**
Muchas gracias

Comment: Puede que la haya, pero así de repente se me ocurre que podrías realizar la consulta de errores vía AJAX y así solucionas el problema, además de que queda más elegante.